# Calculate the "ten year zero rate"  given two bonds with two prices

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, bond

I have a little question and need some help with the notation. So, the question goes as follows:

> A bond with a maturity of ten years that pays annual coupons of 8% has a price of \$90. A bond with a maturity of ten years and annual coupons of 4% has a price of \$80. What is the ten year zero rate?

I don't actually know what the ten-year zero rate is. I set up a system of equations with the information that is given: Is it just all about finding $y$?

\begin{align*}
\$90 =& \sum_{i=1}^{10} e^{-yi} (0.08 Z) &+& e^{-y\cdot 10}Z\\
\$80 =& \sum_{i=1}^{10} e^{-yi} (0.04 Z) &+& e^{-y \cdot 10}Z\\
\Leftrightarrow \$10 =& \sum_{i=1}^{10} e^{-yi} (0.04 Z)\\
\Rightarrow \$70 =& e^{-y\cdot 10}Z
\end{align*}

And is there any way to solve for the zero rate by hand? (This is the reason why I'm wondering; to solve this system, a calculator is necessary, but all the other homework problems were solvable by hand!)

Comment: I'm especially curious now because, when I try to solve this system, I only get $y\approx -0.311$, and I don't think that $y$ should have a negative value here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are trying to solve these equations makes assumptions about the rates less than 10 years and therefore the shape of the yield curve.
\$90 is the value of 8% coupons plus a 10-year zero-coupon bond.
\$80 is the value of the 4% coupons plus a 10-year zero-coupon bond.
8% coupons are worth twice 4% coupons over the same period, regardless of the interest rates.

So 
    90 - 2*80  = value of 8% coupons - 2( value of 4% coupons) - 10-year zero-coupon bond

and

\begin{align*}
\$70 &= e^{-10y} \cdot 100 \\
0.7 &= e^{-10y} \\
\ln(0.7) &= -10 y \\
0.35667 &= 10y \\
y &\approx 3.57 \% \quad\quad\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Okay, so that confirms my initial thought, but how exactly do you get $\approx 3.57\%$, because I only get a value of $\approx -0.311$ when I type this into Mathematica as follows:
$\verb{NSolve[{0.04*Z*Sum[Exp[-y*k], {k, 1, 10}] == 10,70 == Exp[-y*10]*Z},{y, Z}]}$
Does anyone see what I do wrong?

Comment: There is no summation to solve.  I added (corrected) computation.  The only thing you need a calculator for is computing ln(0.7).

Comment: I forgot that we always know that $Z=100$. Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you know Z = 100? ......

Comment: @Caroline That's standard for any bond.